# error while spinning ec2 instance with key using Terraform script

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, devops

I want to provision an ec2 instance with a key and run a script inside an ec2-instance.

filename `instance.tf`

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykey" {
    key_name = "terraform-nverginia"
    public_key = "${file ("${var.PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY}")}"

}   

resource "aws_instance" "demo" {
    ami = "${lookup (var.AMIS, var.AWS_REGION)}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
    tags = {
        Name = "T-instance"
    }

provisioner "file" {   // copying file from local to remote server
   source = "deployscript.sh"
   destination = "/home/ec2-user/deploy.sh"                           //check if both the file names are same or not.
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {                                          // executing script to do some deployment in the server.
      inline = [
         "chmod +x /home/ec2-user/deploy.sh",
         "sudo /home/ec2-user/deploy.sh"
      ]
}

connection {   
    type = "ssh"                                                      // To connect to the instance
    user = "${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME}"
    host = "122.171.19.4"      // My personal laptop's ip address
    private_key = "${file ("${var.PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY}")}"
}

} // end of resource aws_instance
//-------------------------------------------------
```

filename: `provider.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.9.0"
    }
 }
}
```

filename `vars.tf`

```
variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_REGION"{
    default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "AMIS" {
     type = map
     default = {
        us-east-1 = "ami-0574da719dca65348"
        us-east-2 = "ami-0a606d8395a538502"
     }
}

variable "PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY" {
    default = "terraform-nverginia"

}

variable "PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY"{
   default = "mykey.pub"
}

variable "INSTANCE_USERNAME"{
    default = "ec2-user"
}

filename = terraform.tfvars

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "<Access key>"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "<Secret key>"
```

Error:

```
PS D:\\Rajiv\\DevOps-Practice\\Terraform\\demo-2\> terraform plan

╷

│ Error: Invalid provider configuration

│

│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the

│ provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.

│ Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling   sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: G

etCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 594b6dab-e087-4678-8c57-63a65c3d3d41, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The se

curity token included in the request is invalid.

│

│   with provider\["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"\],

│   on \<empty\> line 0:

│ (source code not available)
```

I am expecting a ec2 instance to be created and the script should be run.

Comment: Please learn how to format your question and how to use this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the formatting makes the question unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Providers are plugins which helps Terraform to interact with specific cloud services. You must declare and install cloud provider before you want to use the cloud service via Terraform. Refer to this link https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers. In your code try adding AWS provider.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.48.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  # Configuration options
}
```

Then run terraform init to install the provider.